# Python: Telebot - создание отложенных постов

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Доброго времени суток!

Пытаюсь написать скрипт(бота в тг) который будет создавать пост в чате телеграмм, но не публиковать его сразу, а отправлять в отложенные посты на заданные дату и время.
Использую библиотеку Telebot, но не могу найти подходящий метод, мб кто решал такую задачу уже, или есть идеи как такое можно реализовать?

Реализовать бота который бы работал в фоне, и отправлял посты с задержкой - не вариант.(так же как отдавать скрипт планировщику). Т.е. нужно реализовать так, что бы скрипт был запущен, созданы 5-10 заранее заданных, отложенных поста, в чате тг.

Спасибо.

P.S. Знаний у меня маловато, только начал учить яп. Практикуюсь в написании простеньких вещей, которые мог бы использовать и крутить сам.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Похоже, что для ботов такого функционала ещё нет. Поле `schedule_date` есть только в Core Api

Comment: Благодарю. Спустя пару суток гугла и чтения документации по ботам, мне тоже уже пришла мысль, что через библиотеки ботов эту задачу не решить. Почитал про API на сайте TG, не разобрался(не мой уровень это, пару месяцев только, как начал изучать пайтон).

Answer (score 0):

Вариант решения через pyrogram:

```
from pyrogram import Client, types, raw
from settings import *
from _datetime import datetime

app = Client(name=name_uset_admin, api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash)

async def main(image, date):
    async with app:
        await app.send_photo(channel, photo=image, caption="Set Total", schedule_date=date)

date = datetime(year=2022, month=6, day=17, hour=00, minute=9)
image = "url image"

app.run(main(image, date))
```